# Capturing tables changes

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've got a table that is periodically updated in access.

@EDIT:

This Table is very simple, composed of 2 Collumns. I will represent them with 2 identifiers: Collumn NAME and collumn GRADE. One NAME may have N GRADEs.

/@EDIT

This table is permanent, and 2 operations are done every single day to it: A DELETE to all collumns and a APPEND, done from a linked table that comes from a .txt (that is updated every day).

I need to find a way to create a table with the diferences between the table before and after this APPEND operation. Something like a table with what is new (values that were not present in the last update) and a table with what has been deleted and isn't in this new UPDATE.

I've managed to find a solution in M$' developer's network database that uses SQL Server (Tracking Data Changes seems to be a funcionality in SQL Server), but as I'm new to Access, I would like something less complicated.

Can someone please give me ideas with a solution that I could implement easily to solve my problem?

Comment: Does "what is new" include edits to an existing record?  In other words, are there three categories (New, Deleted, Changed)?

Comment: I recommend you search on `microsoft access audit table`.  The results will focus on auditing one-off edits made via a form, but will be applicable.

Comment: No, only Deleted and New values!
This table has only 2 columns (one of them is the PK, as usual), so we  can't "change" one line... (Deleting one line and not appending a new one like that one means that it has been Deleted, and appending a new line that was not in the previous update means it is New) (:

Comment: The solution may depend on your use for the audit table.  Do you need cumulative history, or just the most recent?

Comment: I wasn't very clear since the begginging. Now It's clearer, i think. Look at my EDIT.

There is a field that identifies it unically. The field NAME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the table and text file include a column with unique values (such as a primary key) which you can use to identify the matching rows, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` on that column and ask for the rows where the "right side" column value is Null.  The result set will include the "left side" rows for which there is no matching row in the "right side" table.

Access has an unmatched query wizard which you may find useful.  But here is a simple example which shows me the `TableA.id` values which are not present in `TableB`.

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM
    TableA AS a
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id Is Null;
```

In your situation, `TableB` could be a link to the text file.  And you would run the query before discarding the rows from `TableA`.

If you must use more than one column to identify the matches, that is also possible and just requires changing the join's `ON` clause.

If you want to store the query's result set in a history table, you can adapt it as an "append query" (`INSERT INTO tblHistory (<field list>) SELECT ....`).

Repeat everything with `TableB` on the "left side" and `TableA` on the "right" to identify which  `TableB` rows are not present in `TableA`.

Comment: Thank you for yout reply, Hans! I will try this and come back here. Anyway, to take the records from TableB that are not in tableA, i would do as follows below?

SELECT b.id
FROM
    TableB AS b
    LEFT JOIN TableA AS a
    ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id Is Null;

Comment: Guys, it works... But now I noticed that when there are too many changes, the select returns NOTHING! Is it normal?

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957007/select-statement-using-left-join