# SELECT statement using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a table that is periodically updated in Access.

This table is very simple, composed of 2 Columns. 
I will represent them with 2 identifiers: Column Operadora and column NDC. One Operadora  may have N NDC.

This table is permanent, and 2 operations are done every single day to it: A DELETE to all columns and an APPEND, done from a linked table that comes from a .txt (that is updated every day).

I need to capture differences between the table that exists before it is appended:
The values that are present in it but are not in the "new" version of the linked table, AND
The values that are not present in it but are in the "new" version of the linked table.

I've managed to find a way of doing this with a LEFT JOIN using some examples, but not with my tables indeed. My table has many values (something like 1000) to be compared, and it is returning only the column names for the SELECT above, even though the same select returns the values i want with another examples.

Here is my SELECT sample to try finding the first part of the problem (values that are present in the table but not in the linked table), so anyone can help me finding the problem:

```
SELECT [1A - NDC_MSISDN].Operadora, [1A - NDC_MSISDN].NDC
FROM [1A - NDC_MSISDN] LEFT JOIN [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT] ON [1A - NDC_MSISDN].[Operadora] = [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT].[Operadora]
WHERE ((([Linked NDC MSISDN TXT].Operadora) Is Null));
```

**PS:**

`1A - NDC_MSISDN` -> Fixed table to be compared (with values "999999")
`Linked NDC MSISDN TXT` -> Linked table to be compared (without values "999999")

Linked NDC MSISDN TXT:

```
Operadora;NDC_MSISDN
A;491
A;492
A;493
A;494
A;495
A;496
A;497
A;498
A;499
A;490
A;770005
B;71
C;82
D;50
E;980
F;385
G;303
G;308
G;402
G;620
G;719
G;785
G;758
G;970
H;9
H;70100
H;70101
H;70102
H;70103
H;801
H;802
H;80769
H;8077
H;8078
H;80790
H;80791
H;80792
H;808
H;8092
H;8095
H;8099
H;9010
H;90111
H;90112
H;9014
H;9015
H;9016
H;90187
H;90188
H;90189
H;90198
H;90199
H;9021
H;9022
H;9023
H;9024
H;9025
H;9026
H;9027
H;9030
H;9031
H;9032
H;9033
H;90340
H;90346
H;90347
H;90348
H;90349
H;9040
H;90411
H;90412
H;90413
H;90414
H;9043
H;9045
H;9046
H;9047
H;9048
H;9049
H;905
H;90669
H;90676
H;90677
H;90678
H;90679
H;90680
H;90681
H;90682
H;90684
H;90688
H;90689
H;9069
H;9070
H;9071
H;9072
H;9073
H;9074
H;9076
H;9077
H;9078
H;9079
H;90800
H;90801
H;90802
H;90803
H;90841
H;90842
H;90857
H;90858
H;90859
H;90863
H;90864
H;90865
H;90866
H;90867
H;90868
H;90869
H;9087
H;9088
H;9089
H;9090
H;9095
I;400
I;401
I;404
I;406
I;408
I;409
I;410
I;411
I;414
I;415
I;416
I;417
I;418
I;419
I;453
I;456
I;457
I;458
I;459
I;461
I;462
I;465
I;466
I;468
I;469
I;470
I;471
I;474
I;475
I;476
I;477
I;478
I;479
I;480
I;481
I;482
I;483
I;484
I;485
I;488
I;489
I;580000
I;5800020
I;58000210
I;5800030
I;5800041
I;5800042
I;5800050
I;5800076
I;580010
I;590
I;591
I;592
I;595
I;900
I;901
I;902
I;903
I;904
I;905
I;906
I;907
I;908
I;909
I;910
I;911
I;912
I;913
I;914
I;915
I;916
I;917
I;918
I;919
I;921
I;923
I;925
I;927
I;929
I;931
I;933
I;935
I;937
I;939
I;940
I;941
I;943
I;944
I;945
I;947
I;948
I;949
I;950
I;951
I;952
I;953
I;954
I;955
I;956
I;957
I;958
I;959
I;960
I;961
I;962
I;963
I;964
I;965
I;966
I;967
I;968
I;969
I;970
I;971
I;972
I;973
I;974
I;975
I;976
I;977
I;979
I;983
I;985
I;987
I;989
I;990
I;991
I;992
I;993
I;994
I;995
```

1A - NDC_MSISDN (With "999999" added to each operadora to exemplify):

```
Operadora;NDC_MSISDN
A;491
A;492
A;493
A;494
A;495
A;496
A;497
A;498
A;499
A;490
A;770005
A;9999999
B;71
B;9999999
C;82
C;9999999
D;50
D;9999999
E;980
E;9999999
F;385
F;9999999
G;303
G;308
G;402
G;620
G;719
G;785
G;758
G;970
G;999999
H;9
H;70100
H;70101
H;70102
H;70103
H;801
H;802
H;80769
H;8077
H;8078
H;80790
H;80791
H;80792
H;808
H;8092
H;8095
H;8099
H;9010
H;90111
H;90112
H;9014
H;9015
H;9016
H;90187
H;90188
H;90189
H;90198
H;90199
H;9021
H;9022
H;9023
H;9024
H;9025
H;9026
H;9027
H;9030
H;9031
H;9032
H;9033
H;90340
H;90346
H;90347
H;90348
H;90349
H;9040
H;90411
H;90412
H;90413
H;90414
H;9043
H;9045
H;9046
H;9047
H;9048
H;9049
H;905
H;90669
H;90676
H;90677
H;90678
H;90679
H;90680
H;90681
H;90682
H;90684
H;90688
H;90689
H;9069
H;9070
H;9071
H;9072
H;9073
H;9074
H;9076
H;9077
H;9078
H;9079
H;90800
H;90801
H;90802
H;90803
H;90841
H;90842
H;90857
H;90858
H;90859
H;90863
H;90864
H;90865
H;90866
H;90867
H;90868
H;90869
H;9087
H;9088
H;9089
H;9090
H;9095
H;9999999
I;400
I;401
I;404
I;406
I;408
I;409
I;410
I;411
I;414
I;415
I;416
I;417
I;418
I;419
I;453
I;456
I;457
I;458
I;459
I;461
I;462
I;465
I;466
I;468
I;469
I;470
I;471
I;474
I;475
I;476
I;477
I;478
I;479
I;480
I;481
I;482
I;483
I;484
I;485
I;488
I;489
I;580000
I;5800020
I;58000210
I;5800030
I;5800041
I;5800042
I;5800050
I;5800076
I;580010
I;590
I;591
I;592
I;595
I;900
I;901
I;902
I;903
I;904
I;905
I;906
I;907
I;908
I;909
I;910
I;911
I;912
I;913
I;914
I;915
I;916
I;917
I;918
I;919
I;921
I;923
I;925
I;927
I;929
I;931
I;933
I;935
I;937
I;939
I;940
I;941
I;943
I;944
I;945
I;947
I;948
I;949
I;950
I;951
I;952
I;953
I;954
I;955
I;956
I;957
I;958
I;959
I;960
I;961
I;962
I;963
I;964
I;965
I;966
I;967
I;968
I;969
I;970
I;971
I;972
I;973
I;974
I;975
I;976
I;977
I;979
I;983
I;985
I;987
I;989
I;990
I;991
I;992
I;993
I;994
I;995
I;999999
```

The output I want with the select is:

```
A;999999
B;999999
C;999999
D;999999
E;999999
F;999999
G;999999
H;999999
I;999999
```

Comment: There are no other fields... The rest of the work is repeating the process to another 20 tables with 2 collumns each too. I ilustrated the problem with this example because the rest is repeating it, but the table has only one collumn

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain myself too well... Now i created an example there, with the real base I am using. I hope you can understand now

Comment: I want the [1A - NDC_MSISDN] rows which are not present in [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT], thats it. Using this sample data, it returns me a blank SELECT, with "Operadora" and "NDC" collumn but no values on them... Thats my problem!

Comment: Do you think the problem could be with the linked table thing?

Comment: No, it isn't... I created a table without being a linked one and it returned me nothing as well :(

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're only joining on one column, but looking for variability in both columns.  So, try updating your join clause:

```
SELECT [1A - NDC_MSISDN].Operadora, [1A - NDC_MSISDN].NDC
FROM [1A - NDC_MSISDN]
  LEFT JOIN [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT]
    ON [1A - NDC_MSISDN].[Operadora] = [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT].[Operadora]
      AND [1A - NDC_MSISDN].[NDC] = [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT].[NDC]
WHERE (([Linked NDC MSISDN TXT].Operadora) Is Null);
```

Comment: Yes, i forgot to mention that I want to do it separatedly, so my problem is actually only with the first half... The second i havent even tried.

Comment: @CharlieVelez, am I understanding the problem now?

Comment: There are lots of lines in [Linked NDC MSISDN TXT], with different NDC values for the same Operadora. With this SELECT, i need to get the LINES that have been removed.

I can still have the same Operadora there, with lots of another NDCs... Or not (in case every NDC of every Operadora isn't present in the new Linked TXT).

Comment: Access is returning me an error, telling me I can not join a memo on this query you posted :/

Comment: Ok, I'm missing something here.  Can you update the question to include a real sample of the data that's causing the problem?

Comment: @CharlieVelez, thanks for the updated question.  The error you're receiving has to do with the datatype of the columns.  Change the datatype of the `[NDC_MSISDN]` column in both tables from `memo` to integer or some equivalent, and give my code another try.

Comment: I need them to be a memo type... I will concatenate these values using a VBA function later :/

Comment: @CharlieVelez, that's generally not considered good practice. The way I'd handle this situation is to store the values as numbers, then convert them to the correct string data type when you need to concatenate them.  However, if you can't do this, try the join clause using the `Val()` function to convert to numbers.  i.e. `Val([1A - NDC_MSISDN].[NDC]) = Val([Linked NDC MSISDN TXT].[NDC])`

Comment: But i can work with memo types using my same come in another tables... I can't figure out a way to understand why in this case it doesn't work...